# FATAL Flags parsing error:Unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorboard

**System information**

1. OS Platform and Distribution: Windows 10 64 Bit
2. TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary
3. TensorFlow version:1.5.0-dev20171115'
4. Python version 3.5.2(v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55)
5. GPU: nVidia GeForce 755M 2GB
6. CPU: Intel x64-64 Intel Core i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50Ghz, 8GB memory

**Describe the problem:**

Initially, the problem I had was is described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2653

The solution given in that is to try and install tf nightly. I did that as shown :
[tfnightly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkI3E.jpg)

However, now when I try to run the following command:

```
C:\Users\kannan\Documents\MDLearning\models\research\object_detection>train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --
pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

**I get the following Error:**

> FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'logtostderr'
>   Pass --helpshort or --helpfull to see help on flags.

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
I omitted --logtostderr and tried the same command. I probably ended up with a memory allocation error from the looks of it as seen here in the PDF attached below. I know it is really long. To make it easy, I have highlighted the important errors: Page 1, 2, 106, 107, 111 and 115.

[PDF-Memory Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZBDClkK7dGtvTf_ckkb7GBqW4zUHC-o/view?usp=sharing)

Any idea how to get around this? I am using a batch size of 1 and it possibly can't go any lower. I have used around 187 images with two classes labelled in each image. All my images are 960 by 720 pixels each. My GPU compute capability is 3.0

Answer (score 0):

`--logtostderr` is not a supported flag see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9830)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, logtostderr was working before I installed tf nightly GPU as mentioned above.